# Highchart label position for solid gauge is too high

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working with highcharts and one of the axis labels is off. After scouring the documentation I wasn't able to find a setting to move them, so I went to jQuery.

The html is:
g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" zIndex="7">
    text x="226.85975458586893" text-anchor="middle" style="width:79px;color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" y="130.37499999999997" opacity="1">1k
    0k
/g>

The y in the first g element needs to be 174 (like the second one).

My attempted jQuery to target it was:
$("g.highcharts-axis-labels") but unsure how to reach the first text tag, much less update the y parameter to be 174.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Please replicate it as live demo and point which label should be positioned in different place

Comment: If you use the highcharts demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/  and change line 62 to 220 (from 200) you can see that the label on the right is now displaying in the gauge.

Comment: Indeed you are right, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3123

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When setting your `yAxis` value define a `tickPositions` array that specifies the minimum and maximum values your gauge should handle.

```
yAxis: {
    max: 220,
    tickPositions: [0, 220]
}
```

These values can also be programatically set.